# apt Always-Include-Phased-Updates not working

Tags: apt, lubuntu, 22.04

I'm  running lubuntu jammy.
I try to configure apt always include phased updates.
My 1. attempt

/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99phased-update

```
#phased-update deaktivieren.
Binary::APT::Get::Always-Include-Phased-Updates "true";
Binary::apt::APT::Always-Include-Phased-Updates "true";
```

Does not work.
2. attempt

```
#phased-update deaktivieren.
Binary::APT::Get::Always-Include-Phased-Updates "1";
Binary::apt::APT::Always-Include-Phased-Updates "1";
```

Sorry for geman output

```
apt-cache policy python3-apport 
python3-apport:
  Installiert:           2.20.11-0ubuntu82.2
  Installationskandidat: 2.20.11-0ubuntu82.3
  Versionstabelle:
     2.20.11-0ubuntu82.3 500 (gestaffelt 10%) (phased)
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
 *** 2.20.11-0ubuntu82.2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.20.11-0ubuntu82.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main i386 Packages
     2.20.11-0ubuntu82 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
```

also not working.

```
apt-config dump | grep -i phased
Binary::apt::APT::Always-Include-Phased-Updates "1";
Binary::apt::Get::Always-Include-Phased-Updates "1";
```

Did I misunderstood something?

Comment: I'll post you an output of my working config in a few hours.. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this content in your `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99phased-update`:

```
// Always include phased updates (Default = true)
APT::Get::Always-Include-Phased-Updates "true";
```

Then retry running the upgrade:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Also, be aware that `apt policy <package-name>` will still show that updates are being phased in:

```
$ apt policy python3-apport
python3-apport:
  Installed: 2.20.11-0ubuntu82.3
  Candidate: 2.20.11-0ubuntu82.3
  Version table:
 *** 2.20.11-0ubuntu82.3 500 (phased 10%)
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.20.11-0ubuntu82.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.20.11-0ubuntu82 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

But it will update nonetheless (as you can see from my installed version, which was installed with unattended-upgrades).